# две mongoose модели при рендеринге страницы

Tags: node.js, mongoose

Здравствуйте. Как использовать две mongose модели при рендеринге страницы?
Вот так не работает

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const content = require('../views/data/content.json');

router.get('/', function (req, res) {
  let obj = {
    title: 'Мои работы',
    reviews: content.reviews
  };
  Object.assign(obj, req.app.locals.settings);

  const Model = mongoose.model('pic');
  //получаем список работ из базы
  Model
    .find()
    .then(items => {
      Object.assign(obj, {items: items});
      res.render('pages/works', obj);
    });


  const Model2 = mongoose.model('reviews');
  //получаем список ревью из базы
  Model2
    .find()
    .then(reviews => {
      Object.assign(obj, {ReviewList: reviews});
      res.render('pages/works', obj);
    });
});
```

Comment: А почему у вас два раза рендерится страница? Запросы к монге асинхронные, сделайте используйте промисы для рендера страницы после обоих запросов.

Comment: спасибо. пока новичок в node))
Такое решение заработало
`router.get('/', function (req, res) {
  let obj = {
    title: 'Мои работы'
  };
  Object.assign(obj, req.app.locals.settings); 
  
  Promise.all([mongoose.model('pic').find(), mongoose.model('reviews').find()])
    .then(result => {
      Object.assign(obj, {pic: result[0], reviews: result[1]});
      res.render('pages/works', obj);
    });
});
`

Comment: Вот так гораздо лучше. Там фишка в том, что по умолчанию на 1 запрос можно рендерить только 1 раз страницу и ещё важный момент: кроме рендера выставить заголовок ответа или сделать редирект тоже можно лишь один раз, иначе будет ошибка, так что проверяйте всегда логику работы страницы, если логика уловная, условия ставьте в самом начале роутера.

Answer (score 0):

Самый дедовский способ - объявить переменную-счётчик `var count = 0;` в начале, и в обоих случаях его плюсовать и обусловливать:

```
Object.assign(obj, {items: items});
count++;
if(count == 2)
  res.render('pages/works', obj);
```

Так и делали до того, пока добрый человек не написал библиотеку `async` - собсно, она делает то же самое "за кулисами", плюс разные варианты подхода `async.parallel`, `async.foreach` и т.д.. А потом в стандарте появились `Promise` и генераторы. Короче, много вариантов, но "дедовский" - вполне работает, естественно.

Ну и, в `Express` же есть специальный объект - `res.locals`, - для сбора в нём всех данных для динамической генерации. Если собирать в него, то его и не нужно передавать вторым аргументом в `res.render` (он уже там есть). Но можно, конечно, и так - свой создавать.

Answer (score 0):

Используй Promise.all, не решай больше задачи таким способом! 
Пример:

```
router.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
  return db.sequelize.Promise.all([
    Model.find(),
    Model2.find()
  ])
  .spread((dataModel1, dataModel2) => {
    return res.render('pages/works', {
      title: 'Мои работы',
      reviews: content.reviews, // правда не понятно от куда у тебя беретя эта переменная
      dataModel1,
      dataModel2
    });
  })
  .catch(next);
}
```